# PHP $Globals variables reset to default values when you change page

Tags: php

I have a file called vars.php which stores things like my database connection string and three other variables (let's call them `$a`, `$b` and `$c`). It is set up like this

```
<?php
$dbname='MY_DB_NAME';
$dbusername='MY_DB_USERNAME';
$dbpassword='MY_DB_PASSWORD';
$database='MY_DB_SERVER';

$a = "";
$b = "";
$c = 0;
?>
```

On my login page, I enter some data which is then sent to an API which returns some JSON which I deserialise and store in $a, $b and $c like this

```
if (!empty($data['SomeData']) {
    global $a, $b, $c; // same names as in the vars.php file
    $a = $data['SomeData']['param1'];
    $b = $data['SomeData']['param2'];
    $c = $data['SomeData']['param3'];
    header('Location: nextpage.php');
}
```

When nextpage.php fires up, the first thing it does is call a helper that calls an API to get some other data. The problem is that when I hit nextpage.php, $a, $b and $c have reverted to the default values rather than the values I've set them it (I have also tried the likes of

```
$GLOBALS['c'] = $data['SomeData']['param3'];
```

but this also returns the default value [in this case `0`])

From my understanding, both of these ways of setting the global scope variable should be fine, but I must be missing something. How do I get $a, $b and $c to retain the values I set them to on my first page?

Due to a policy at the company this is for, cookies aren't an option (don't ask - it took ages for them to agree to some very simple JS!)

Comment: This is what sessions are for

Comment: Global is regarding scope, not existence beyond the lifetime of the script itself.

Comment: They for holding data that is used throughout the website - I'd normally not think twice and use a cookie, but can't on this occassion

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php